# Unexpected behavior of filtering RDD with var

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have encountered a weird bug in my code and while debugging I was able to refine the problem. The thing is that when I filter a `var` RDD with a `var` variable and then store the filter results in the same RDD the RDD is updated correctly.
The thing is that after I update the var variable I used to filter the result I automatically **filter again!**

example code:

```
var filter = 5
var a1 = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))
a1 = a1.filter(t => !t.equals(filter))
a1.foreach(println) // result is: 1-9 without 5
filter = filter + 1
a1.foreach(println) // result is: 1-9 without 6
```

Why is that happening? what is the rule for this not to cause bug in my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spark transformations are lazily evaluated. When you do `a1.filter`, you get back a `FilteredRDD`, you don't actually have the *result of the computation* at that point in time. Only when you request and action on the transformation with `foreach`, only then is the transformation invoked.

As well as the lazy filtering, the lambda expression captures the *variable*, not the value. This means that when you update `filter`, the same variable inside the captured lambda is updated from 5 to 6, and then filtering it again yields all elements with the updated value.

Comment: thx for the answer, +1 for pointing the lambda expression captures the variable! I know about the lazy evaluation but didn't think of its application with a var variable.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the a1 contains the complete DAG . And foreach is an action which will trigger the DAG to get the result.

```
scala> var a1 = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))
a1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[4] at parallelize at <console>:21

scala> a1.toDebugString
res5: String = (4) ParallelCollectionRDD[4] at parallelize at <console>:21 []

scala> a1 = a1.filter(t => !t.equals(filter))
a1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = MapPartitionsRDD[5] at filter at <console>:25


scala> a1.toDebugString
res6: String = 
(4) MapPartitionsRDD[5] at filter at <console>:25 []
 |  ParallelCollectionRDD[4] at parallelize at <console>:21 []
```

So whenever you print the rdd using foreach it will take the filter value in closure and get you the result by computing the DAG.

```
filter = 6
a1.foreach(println) // will filter 6
filter = 9
a1.foreach(println) // will filter 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these and see what happens:

```
var filter = 5
var a1 = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))
a1 = sc.parallelize(a1.filter(t => !t.equals(filter)).collect())
a1.foreach(println)
filter = filter + 1
a1.foreach(println)
```

And this also:

```
var filter = 5
var a1 = sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))
a1 = a1.filter(t => !t.equals(filter)).cache()
a1.foreach(println)
filter = filter + 1
a1.foreach(println)
```

Hope these will make you think more!